# How to pass Anonymous type result in a viewbag and Render the same in Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, view

I'm trying to find out the book publications count in each Department and want to render the same in view. But i'm getting error like

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

```
Source Error: 
Line 20:         <tr>
Line 21:             <td>
Line 22:                @item.Key
Line 23:                 
Line 24:             </td>
```

here is the Controller code

```
 public ActionResult BooksCount()
    {
    ViewBag.booksGroup= db.BookPublications.GroupBy(x => x.FacultyDepartment)
           .Select(y => new { FacultyDepartment = y.Key, DepartmentCount = y.Count() });


        return View();
    }
```

Here is my View

```html
   @model Iam.Models.BookPublication
<h2>Books Count</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th>
            Count
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.booksGroup)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               @item.Key
                
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Count()
                
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue building an ASP.NET app with the Entity Framework - it wouldn't accept anonymous types, so I went ahead and built a ViewModel class.

In a nutshell, it is just a plain and simple class with properties, but the type definition allows you to pass it to the ViewBag, assuming your serializer in the background does its job.

So create a little class like

```
public class BookPublicationViewModel
{
   public FacultyDepartment { get; set; }
   public DepartmentCount   { get; set; }
}
```

And change your LINQ Statement to this:

```
 public ActionResult BooksCount()
{
ViewBag.booksGroup= db.BookPublications.GroupBy(x => x.FacultyDepartment)
       .Select(y => new BookPublicationViewModel{ FacultyDepartment = y.Key, DepartmentCount = y.Count() });


    return View();
}
```

Edit:

```
Line 20:         <tr>
Line 21:             <td>
Line 22:                @item.Key
Line 23:                 
Line 24:             </td>
```

Should of course be changed to the actual name of the property you assigned in the select statement, e.g. @Item.Key -> @item.FacultyDepartment

```
Line 20:         <tr>
Line 21:             <td>
Line 22:                @item.FacultyDepartment
Line 23:                 
Line 24:             </td>
```

As @Alexi already mentioned.

EDIT: @Pratik mentioned that **razor actually DOES accept anonymous types** - not sure why it wouldn't work on my end. In this case, changing your property names in the View to match them should be enough to fix your issue.

Comment: Although your suggestion is correct way to go, it’s not entirely true. `razor` does accept anonymous types. @Michel hasn’t tried to extract value by correct name of the property from the anonymous object he has created.

Comment: Interesting. I kept getting errors about a lack of definition when using anon types on my end. Thanks for the heads-up though, edited. :)

Answer (score 2):

Correct property name for access is

> FacultyDepartment

not the

> key

```
 @model Iam.Models.BookPublication
<h2>Books Count</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th>
            Count
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.booksGroup)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               @item.FacultyDepartment

            </td>
            <td>
                @item.DepartmentCount 

            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```